# What's the correct way to put a line under a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, underline

I want to have a borderless UITextField but underneath have a 1 or 2 pixel high guide line that underlines the field. To be clear, I don't want just the text INSIDE the UITextField to be underlined, but the field, whether it's empty or full of text.

An example is seen in this example of Google Material Design:

[image]

So of course I could just stick in a UIImage that shows a solid color and fit it to that space, but that doesn't seem quite elegant, is there a better way that's more "correct" and future-proof if I'm worrying about how my code will work several generations of iOS down the line and on who knows what devices?

p.s. would rather do this from scratch using Obj-C than find a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just did this yesterday... Subclass UITextField and this will work.

Note: It would be cleaner though to use textFieldDidBeginEditing: and textFieldDidEndEditing: to do the changing of the line height and color, either through NSNotificationCenter or delegate methods.

```
- (void)setup 
{
    self.hairlineLayer = [CALayer layer];
    self.hairlineLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor materialTextDarkDividerColor].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.hairlineLayer];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat hairlineHeight = 0;
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {
        self.hairlineLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        hairlineHeight = 1.4;
    } else {
        self.hairlineLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        hairlineHeight = 1/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }

    self.hairlineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - hairlineHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), hairlineHeight);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, btw why do you use 1/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale for the gray bar, but just 1.4 with no division for the editing color?

Comment: I wanted it 1.4 so it was a bit thicker when editing and I use  1/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale because that is what the exact divider width for UITableViewCells is, it just always gives a consistent good size for dividers.

Comment: Right, but I'm confused, which is TOTALLY my issue lol, but wouldn't it make sense to do 1.4/[UIScreen mainscreen.scale]; for the same reasons you dion't use 1.0 by itself? I only ask because I'm confused not because I think you're wrong though, I am simple confused Brazilian!

Comment: Yea sure that sounds like a good idea too, but just use whatever size you want for the divider, whatever looks good for you!

Comment: Cool my friend. I implemented something very close to this but when I use auto layout constraints on it, the text inside the text area moves a pixel or two closer to the bottom line, Unsure if that was my simple-headed changes or not, that happen for you?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new GlobalClass

Declare a Method in GlobalClass.h

```
+(void)UnderLineStyleTextField:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Define a Method in GlobalClass.m

```
+(void)UnderLineStyleTextField:(UITextField *)textField
{
CALayer *textFieldbottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
textFieldbottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, textField.frame.size.height - 1, textField.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
textFieldbottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[textField.layer addSublayer:textFieldbottomBorder];
}
```

Import GlobalClass in ViewController

Call GlobalClass Method From ViewDidLoad

```
[GlobalClass UnderLineStyleTextField:txtForgotPasswods];
```